# Kingfisher not loading images in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, kingfisher

I am trying to implement Kingfisher to handle my images because I am doing them manually at the moment and it's not good. I seem to be having some issues though.

I downloaded this pod via CocoaPods:

```
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 7.0'
```

And I changed this code:

```swift
import Kingfisher

if let dataDecoded: NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: businessData.business_logo ?? "", options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) {
        if let decodedimage: UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded as Data) {
            Image(uiImage: decodedimage)
               .resizable()
        }
}
```

To this code:

```swift
import Kingfisher

if let url = URL(string: businessData.business_logo ?? "") {
    KFImage(url)
      .resizable()
}
```

When I run the code, this is printed to the console:

```
2023-05-08 17:58:33.751513+0100 Project Name[23531:243997] Task <1F4ADD8F-C550-460C-87B3-307E9BDFFD20>.<1> finished with error [-1002] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL,
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? Is there a SwiftUI version of the pod I need?

Comment: In your first code block, business_logo seems to be a Base64 encoded String, but on the next you’re trying to use it as a URL. Kingfisher expects a URL string to download the image, but it seems like you’ve already downloaded it.

Comment: Check your URL address, if it not secret send it in comment